Horror movie, watched back in 2003, invisible creature attacking people
The movie starts by women and children being locked up in a safe house because there is an invisible creature attacking them. The men with swords await for the creature outside the house not knowing that the creature got locked up together with the women and children.  
The creature kills all of them inside.  The men did not open the door immediately cause it was highly locked. 
At some point one of the main actors dreams of a very beautiful woman, this woman appears in his dreams always until some point he is unable to sleep.
Again there is one main actor as well, an old man with white hair who helps in killing this creature at the end, the blood spills from this creature and goes to the woman the other man has been dreaming of, this woman turns to be a very ugly creature again with branchlike hands which results to another fighting with the actor with white hair.  Finally he sticks his sword at its leg then attaches it to electricity and its electrocuted.  
Additional information:
It's like an ancient Rome movie. Coloured. There is a moment the starring actor tells his girlfriend "ghosts don't eat people"; then there is another place one man's eye glasses fall down, then a very beautiful woman seduces him and he has sex with her; finally, she kills him. When the starring actor comes to the house of this man, his body falls unto him killed. I don't know the year of release but I watched it in 2003, it was in English, showing for 2 hours 22 minutes. The starring actor has white hair, he comes to this village on a horse, and they harass him at first but he is their saviour. The co-starring actor is a dreamer always dreaming about this beautiful woman, who finally changes into a disgusting creature.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in?  Descriptions  or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

I'm dying to know how you remember it was 2 hours 22 minutes long! :)

Part of what you're describing sounds like Beowulf http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0442933/.  Beowulf has the swords, the colour asthetic, the guy with white hair, the dream of the beautiful woman.  I can't help thinking you're mixing two films together here.

Thank you so much.  It is the one.  Beowulf year 1999.  Thanks alot.  Been thinking how to get it.

@Tim Nicely done. Seems you can put it up as an answer.
